# Qt application,there flicker appears when switch page on linux-arm platform

Tags: linux, qt, embedded-linux

Qt version: 4.8.6

The application deploys on `arm-linux` by cross-compiler. On my PC, everything works well. This issue appears on `arm-linux` platform. If the coming page contains `QWidget` object this issue will appear.

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::Widget)
{ 
    ui->setupUi(this); 
    QDesktopWidget deskWidget; 
    this->resize(deskWidget.availableGeometry().size()); 
    //main page 
    this->setPalette(QPalette(QColor(Qt::black)));
    QPushButton* button = new QPushButton("to next",this);
    connect(button,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(onButtonClick())); 
}

void Widget::onButtonClick() 
{ 
    QDialog dialog(this); 
    dialog.resize(size());
    QWidget* topW = new QWidget(&dialog);
    QPushButton* button1 = new QPushButton("back",&dialog);
    connect(button1,SIGNAL(clicked()),&dialog,SLOT(accept()));
    QVBoxLayout* lw = new QVBoxLayout; 
    lw->addWidget(topW); 
    lw->addWidget(button1);
    dialog.setLayout(lw); 
    dialog.exec(); 
}
```

picture 1,open the dialog,there is obvious flicker,but if i remove the widget in dialog,just set the dialog's background-color black,this is no flicker,for example get back to the main window(picture 2)

When click button to show dialog

[image]

When click the button on dialog to get back to main window

[image]

Comment: What issue ?  You say there is an error but you don't even tell us what it is !

Comment: sorry ,i don't know how to describe the issue with english, may be call flicker suitable

Comment: What's happening ? Can you post an image ? One little extract of your code won't help me to help you...

Comment: i will upload a gif later

Comment: @Xatyrian would you please have a look,i have upload the gif.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why this happened,but i solved it by add one line code
    `void Widget::onButtonClick()`
    `{`
    `QDialog dialog(this);`
    `dialog.setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground);`
    `}`